# How to pass values from a html page using jQuery to PHP and get a response back?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to pass the values from jQuery to PHP. Here is my code,

jQuery Function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#contact_form").submit(function () {
            var RequesterName = $("#RequesterName").val(); 
            var Requestoremail = $("#Requestoremail").val();
            var Subject = '[Request] Mail Subject';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json', 
                url: 'sendmail.php',
                data: { RequesterName_val: RequesterName, Requestoremail_val: Requestoremail, Subject_val: Subject },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Mail Sent Successsfully');
                }
            });
        });
    })
```

and PHP:

```
<?php
    $to = $_POST['RequesterName_val'];
    $subject = $_POST['Subject_val'];
    $RequesterName = $_POST['RequesterName_val'];
    $Requestoremail = $_POST['Requestoremail_val'];

     $message = "RequesterName:".$RequesterName."   , Requestoremail:".$Requestoremail."    ";

                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

                // More headers
                $headers .= 'From: <'.$Requestoremail.'>' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Reply-To: '.$Requestoremail.'\r\n";

                 if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
                        echo "Success";
                 } else {
                             echo "Error";
                 }

      die();

?>
```

It seems mail is triggering from php  but I am not getting a response back and "Mail Sent Successfully" is not displaying in jQuery? How can i get a response for success and failure of mail trigger?

Comment: you're telling jquery to expect json back, and then sending a bare success/error string. that'll cause a json parse error and NOT trigger the ajax success handler.

Comment: Are you getting the javascript alert? Agreed with @MarcB

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Hello, looks like my code is fine.. I am getting mail. Only problem is I am not getting alert after sending mail, alert('Mail Sent Successsfully'); is not working. Any idea why?

Comment: Because you're not returning JSON. When it gets an error trying to parse the response, it doesn't go into the `success:` function.

Comment: Can you help me ?. I should get a response back from php. how to do it?

Comment: @Rameez, 2 people already told you what the problem is. You just need to either use `json_encode` to return a proper `json` object or tell your jquery to not expect a json but a text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$.ajax` call says that the response should be JSON, but you're just returning plain text. When jQuery gets an error trying to parse the JSON, it doesn't call the `success:` callback.

You can either correct the PHP so it returns JSON:

```
echo json_encode(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers));
die();
```

Then in the `success` function you would write:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data) {
        alert('Mail sent successfully');
    } else {
        alert('Mail not sent');
    }
}
```

or you can change the `$.ajax` call to use `dataType: 'text'`, and the callback would be:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data == 'Success') {
        alert('Mail sent successfully');
    } else {
        alert('Mail not sent');
    }
}
```

Comment: Super macha.. Thanks